# How to control where a tar file extracts by default, using tarfile?

Tags: python

I'm creating a .tar.gz file using this python code:

```
import tarfile
def main():
    tar = tarfile.open("poc.tar.gz", "w:gz")
    tar.addfile(tarfile.TarInfo("tehfile.txt"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Currently, when using tar to open the created file (poc.tar.gz), the extracted content (tehfile.txt) is outputted to the current directory.

How can I pre-determine to which location "tehfile.txt" will be extracted to?

I could've done it with tar:

```
tar -xf file_name.tar -C /target/directory
```

But I wan't to **pre-determine** the target directory!

Comment: This is not a programming question. Also, there are good reasons for the default to be like this. If you need something else, use the argument.

Comment: How is a question about a python module isn't a programming question?? and what is "the argument" you're referring to?

Comment: You cannot "pre-determine" the extracted location of files. The security implications of being able to place arbitrary files at arbitrary filesystem locations are significant.

Comment: your first statement is not true.
https://github.com/snyk/zip-slip-vulnerability

Comment: create script which extracts from tar to current folder and then it copies files to expected folder. OR script which copies tar to expected folder and then it extracts from tar.